# ffi library for perl for accessing dlls

Tags: perl, cpan, ffi

I have a dll library for specfic software and need to convert it to perl api .
on Python there are a library called ctypes http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html which is a forign function library which let you access dlls and shared libraries ,

with perl i know that there are win32::api which can also acess dlls on windows but its cumbersome ,
are there any mature perl module /library as python ctypes which one can use for accessing dll exported functions ?